# The new job listing search results format is less readable

Tags: discussion, jobs

I appreciate the effort that goes into development, but the new job listing results format is less readable than it was before.

The job title itself was the most useful piece of information in the listing in terms of determining a match, but it's been reduced in prominence in favor of increasing the size of the 1) company name and 2) logo.

Neither of these attributes matter more to me as a job seeker than the title and description. A company's name indicates nothing, and the same is true of the logo thumbnails. Okay, it's a white 'H' in the middle of a blue square, so what? ;) That tells me far less than the title and description, which I have to practically squint at relative to the size of the less important attributes!

They're also indented, making them harder to scan, while the (non-useful) logo thumbnail is (again) parsed first, left to right.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the B side of a split test we're running.  This test is still underway, but we'll be wrapping it up soon.

Comment: Thanks Will, I hope I'm not disparaging anyone's hard work too much (I'm a developer, too). The changes I saw are admittedly no different from many sites that have moved away from grid formats over the last few years, but it has sacrificed some usability and readability in the name of design. I'm seeing the older style results today, and they're much easier to scan with a smoother, less jagged edge with fewer indentations, in my opinion.

Comment: @SexxLuthor You're not.  We're not too thinned skinned.  The experiment results were pretty interesting.  The traffic to jobs and company pages stayed about flat, but we had a small but noticeable drop in application rates.  So your comment was consistent with what we found, and we've now ended it.  We are going to keep trying obviously, and probably failing a few more times, to create a better search result page that highlights companies.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing the outcome. Also somewhat surprising--I wouldn't have expected a noticeable change in results, because it's not like I'm going to stop looking or applying for jobs, it's just a little more tedious to do so, if it takes more effort to scan the listings (from my perspective).